# How to Check for Two Columns and Query Every Table When They Exist?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I'm interested in doing a `COUNT(*)`, `SUM(LENGTH(blob)/1024./1024.)`, and `ORDER BY SUM(LENGTH(blob))` for my entire database when column 'blob' exists.  For tables where synchlevels **does not** exist, I still want the output.  I'd like to `GROUP BY` that column:

Example

```
+--------+------------+--------+-----------+
|  table | synchlevel | count  |  size_mb  |
+--------+------------+--------+-----------+
| tableA |          0 | 924505 |   3013.47 |
| tableA |          7 |    981 |    295.33 |
| tableB |          6 |   1449 |    130.50 |
| tableC |          1 |  64368 |     68.43 |
| tableD |       NULL |    359 |       .54 |
| tableD |       NULL |    778 |       .05 |
+--------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

I would like to do a pure SQL solution, but I'm having a bit of difficulty with that.  Currently, I'm wrapping some SQL into BASH.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=$1
DBNAME=$2

function psql_cmd(){
    cmd=$1
    prefix='\pset border 2 \\ '
    echo $prefix $cmd | psql -U $USER $DBNAME | grep -v "Border\| row"
}

function synchlevels(){
    echo "===================================================="
    echo "                 SYNCH LEVEL STATS                  " 
    echo "===================================================="
    tables=($(psql -U $USER -tc "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE column_name = 'blob';" $DBNAME))
    for table in ${tables[@]}; do
        count_size="SELECT t.synchlevel,
                        COUNT(t.blob) AS count,
                        to_char(SUM(LENGTH(t.blob)/1024./1024.),'99999D99') AS size_mb
                      FROM $table AS t
                      GROUP BY t.synchlevel
                      ORDER BY SUM(LENGTH(t.blob)) DESC;"
        echo $table
        psql_cmd "$count_size"
    done
    echo "===================================================="
}
```

I could extend this by creating a second **tables** BASH array of tables which have the 'synchlevel' column, compare and use that list to run through the SQL, but I was wondering if there was a way I could just do the SQL portion purely in SQL without resorting to making these lists in BASH and doing the comparisons externally.  i.e. I want to avoid needing to externally loop through the tables and making numerous queries in `tables=($(psql -U $USER...`.

I've tried the following SQL to test on a table where I know the column doesn't exist...

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns 
                WHERE column_name = 'synchlevel' 
            AND table_name = 'archivemetadata')
      THEN synchlevel
    END,
  COUNT(blob) AS count,
  to_char(SUM(LENGTH(blob)/1024./1024.),'99999D99') AS size_mb
 FROM archivemetadata, information_schema.columns AS info
 WHERE info.column_name = 'blob'
```

However, it fails on `THEN synchlevel` for tables where it doesn't exist.  It seems really simple to do, but I just can't seem to find a way to do this which doesn't require either:

1. Resorting to external array comparisons in BASH.

   - Can be done, but I'd like to simplify my solution rather than add another layer.
2. Creating PL/PGSQL functions.

   - This script is really just to help with some database data analysis for improving performance in a third-party software.  We are not a shop of DB Admins, so I would prefer not to dive into PL/PGSQL as that would require more folks from our shop to also become acquainted with the language in order to support the script.  Again, simplicity is the motivation here.

Postgresql 8.4 is the engine.  (We cannot upgrade due to security constraints by an overseeing IT body.)

Thanks for any suggestions you might have!

Answer (score 1):

The following is untested, but how about creating some dynamic sql in one psql session and piping it to another?

```
psql -d <yourdb> -qtAc "
select  'select ' || (case when info.column_name = 'synchlevel' then 'synchlevel,' else '' end) ||
        'count(*) as cnt,' ||
        'to_char(SUM(LENGTH(blob)::NUMERIC/1024/1024),''99999D99'') AS size_mb' ||
        'from ' || info.table_name ||
        (case when info.column_name = 'synchlevel' then ' group by synchlevel order by synchlevel' else '' end)
from information_schema.columns as info
where info.table_name IN (select distinct table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'blob')" | psql -d <yourdb>
```

Comment: I've looked into this method and tested out a number of things.  Unfortunately, this is still just barely short of what I'm after.  I'd like to see this done as a single query where I could get the output in a single table, and I can see how my question says otherwise.  This is an apt solution for how my issue is described currently, and I'll update the question to reflect that.  Thanks!